# Technical Details in do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am confused about a proof in do Carmo's *Riemannian Geometry*. The following side-to-side screenshots are pages 227 - 228 in Section 4 of Chapter 10. I have included them so as to keep the question self-contained. The main post is directly below the pictures. If it helps, we may assume that $N$ is an embedded submanifold (the case I care about).

[image: DC proof]

For reference's sake, I will also include a screenshot of the "Weingarten equation" theorem from Chapter 6 of the same book.

[image: Weingarten]

---

I am confused about do Carmo's proof of property (ii). do Carmo writes
$$
\frac{DA}{ds}(0) = \left.\overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}A(s)\right|_{s = 0}.
$$
The right-hand side doesn't make a lot of sense to me. $A(s)$ is a vector field defined along a curve and not on an open subset of $M$. If $A(s)$ is extendible to a vector field $X$ in a neighborhood of $p$ with $X(\alpha(s)) = A(s)$ for small enough $s$, then the definition of $DA/ds(0)$ implies that $DA/ds(0) = \overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}X$, and then we could continue the proof just fine. I cannot think of any other possible interpretation for the right-hand side of the above equation. But what if $A(s)$ is not extendible? Is there something that guarantees it in this case, or is this a missing assumption?

> **Question 1:** How do we choose such a vector field $X$ on $M$ near $p$, such that for small enough $s$, $X(\alpha(s)) = A(s)$? (Are we necessarily able to in this case, or is do Carmo omitting an important hypothesis?)

If, for example, $\alpha'(0) = J(0) \neq 0$, then $\alpha$ is locally an embedding, and so I can find local coordinates $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ for $M$ with $\alpha(s) = (0, \dots, 0, s)$, and then extend $A$ in the obvious way, But what if $J(0) = 0$? I do not see what to do in this case. It suffices in this case to prove that $J'(0) \in (T_pM)^\perp$, but I don't know how to show this.

Now, let's assume that we've chosen such an $X$. I interpret the last equation as saying that
$$
\left.\left\langle\left(\overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}A(s)\right)^\top,v\right\rangle\right|_{s = 0} = \left\langle \left(\overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}X\right)^\top,v\right\rangle = \left\langle -S_{\gamma'(0)}(J(0)), v \right\rangle,
$$
where the last equality supposedly follows from the Weingarten equation (reference above). In order to apply this, we have to choose our local extension $X$ in such a way that $X$ is normal to $N$.

> **Question 2:** As a follow-up to Question 1, how can we choose $X$ normal to $N$?

---

I apologize for the very long post. Any insights or help would be appreciated. I haven't been able to find anything on this online or in other textbooks, which is why I've decided to post this. If anyone could share any references with proofs of the fact do Carmo is proving, that would also be very helpful. (Of course, if I am making a fundamental misunderstanding and overcomplicating something, I would also welcome that as an answer.)

---

*Edit:* Inspired by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/205203/844285) post, I noticed that Question 1 can be whittled down to a specific case. If $\alpha'(0) \neq 0$, then, as I remarked above, we can extend $A(s)$. (The question of how to choose the extension normal to $N$ still stands.) If $\alpha'(s) = 0$ for all $s$ sufficiently close to $0$, then $\alpha(s) \equiv p$ for small $s$. In this case, $A(s)$ is a curve in the vector space $(T_pN)^\perp$, so it follows that $J'(0) = DA/ds(0) = dA/ds(0) \in (T_pN)^\perp$, which proves (ii) directly. It only remains to figure out what happens when we have a sequence $s_n \to 0$ with $\alpha'(s_n) \neq 0$ but $\alpha'(0) = 0$. This, I have made no progress on.

Comment: I'm not sure how the author construct $\alpha(s)$ here, but I think we got to choose $\alpha$ such that it behaves nicely, that is it is an embedding of $N$. That way it is easier to construct such extension of $A(s)$.

Comment: I found this result as a problem in Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds book. Lee does not assume that the curve in the submanifold is an embedding (but he does explicitly state that the submanifold is embedded, if that changes anything). This leads me to think the proof should still work if the curve is not an embedding, but you could be correct.

Comment: Can you tell me where is that specific problem in Lee's?

Comment: @Kelvin Lois It is problem 10-14(b). The displayed equation is [errata](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/RM/errata.pdf), and should match i) and ii) of do Carmo's book (the first page above), with $0$ replaced by $a$ and $S$ replaced by $W$. I should also note that Lee assumes in this problem that $J$ is normal, something which do Carmo doesn't do.

Comment: This is a recurring question on MSE. Abstractly, you have to pull back, using $f$, the tangent bundle $T_*M$ to a vector bundle $f^*T_*M$ over $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\times[0,\ell]$ and the connection on $M$ to a connection on $f^*T_*M$, prove the identity there, and observe that the identity can be pushed forward to $M$. I think here it means you do everything using $\frac{D}{dt}$ and $\frac{D}{dt}$ and, only at the end, observe that the conclusion can be pushed forward to $M$.

Comment: @Deane Thank you. It's awfully specific, but would you happen to know of any references (textbooks, articles, papers, etc.) that discuss or work with pullback connections in the context of variations? The notion of a pullback connection in the pullback bundle is relatively new to me, and I'm interested in learning more, especially about how it applies to the problem in my post. I hope that it might lead me to a cleaner answer than the one I've posted below.

Comment: How to deal with the pullbacks of a vector bundle and connection always bothered me. So I finally worked out the details. It’s posted here: https://deaneyang.github.io//blog/blog/math/differential-geometry/riemannian-geometry/2021/04/01/PullbackConnection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I haven't made any mistakes in the following, no extensions are necessary. It boils down to a computation in the right frame. (I'm curious to know if there's a reasonable coordinate/frame-free proof; Deane's comment leads me to believe there might be one, in terms of pullback connections.) Let $E_1,\dots,E_m,\dots,E_n$ be a local orthonormal frame near $p$ adapated to $N$ (i.e., $(E_1,\dots,E_m)$ is an orthonormal frame for $N$ along $N$). Write

$$
A(s) = \sum_{i=m+1}^n A^i(s) E_i(f(s, 0))
$$

for some functions $A^{m+1},\dots,A^n$. The covariant derivative $DA/ds(0)$ is easily computed:

\begin{align*}
\frac{DA}{ds}(0) &= \sum_{i=m+1}^n \left.\frac{D}{ds} A^i(s)E_i(f(s,0))\right|_{s=0} \\
&= \sum_{i=m+1}^n \left[ \frac{d A^i}{d s}(0) E_i(p) + A^i(0)\left.\frac{D}{ds}E_i(f(s,0))\right|_{s=0} \right] \\
&= \sum_{i=m+1}^n \left[ \frac{d A^i}{d s}(0) E_i(p) + A^i(0) \overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}E_i\right] \\
&= \sum_{i=m+1}^n \left[ \frac{d A^i}{d s}(0) E_i(p) + \sum_{j=1}^n A^i(0) \omega_i{}^j(J(0))E_j(p)\right],
\end{align*}
where $(\omega_i{}^j)$ is the matrix of connection forms for $\overline\nabla$ with respect to $E_1,\dots,E_n$. Taking the tangential part gives

$$
\tag{1}
\left(\frac{DA}{ds}(0)\right)^\top = \sum_{j=1}^m \left(\sum_{i=m+1}^n A^i(0)\omega_i{}^j(J(0))\right)E_j(p).
$$

Now let's compute $-S_{\gamma'(0)}(J(0))$:

\begin{align*}
-S_{\gamma'(0)}(J(0)) &= -\sum_{j=1}^m \langle S_{\gamma'(0)}(J(0)), E_j(p) \rangle E_j(p) \\
&= -\sum_{j=1}^m \langle \gamma'(0), (\overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}E_j)^\perp \rangle E_j(p) \\
&= -\sum_{j=1}^m \langle \gamma'(0), \overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}E_j \rangle E_j(p) \\
&= -\sum_{j=1}^m \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \langle \gamma'(0), E_i(p)\rangle \omega_j{}^i(J(0))\right) E_j(p) \\
&= -\sum_{j=1}^m \left(\sum_{i=m+1}^n A^i(0) \omega_j{}^i(J(0))\right) E_j(p).
\end{align*}

Since the matrix of connection forms in an orthonormal frame is skew-symmetric, this equals (1), and we conclude

$$
\left(\frac{DA}{ds}(0)\right)^\top = -S_{\gamma'(0)}(J(0)),
$$

what we wanted to prove.

Answer (score 0):

A(s) is a vector field along $\alpha(s)$ and $\alpha'(0)=J(0)$. Then by definition of the covariant derivative $(DA/ds)(0)$, one has the first equation.

Comment: I guess that one of my issues is that the term $$\left.\overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}A(s)\right|_{s = 0}$$ which do Carmo writes doesn't really make sense to me, and that I'm trying to figure out what he meant. $A(s)$ is only defined along a curve, so what does the above term mean, if not $\overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}X$ for some local extension $X$ of $A$? And I don't see why $A$ should be extendible in the first place. (My first question.) I've updated my post to more clearly reflect these concerns.

Comment: why do you want to extend $A$?. Recall that to compute $\nabla_XY$ at a point $p$ you only need the vector $X(p)$ and the values $Y(t):=Y(\alpha(t))$ where  $\alpha(t)$ is smooth curve such that $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=X(p)$

Comment: The Weingarten equation implies that $-S_{A(0)}(J(0)) = (\overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}X)^\top$, where $X$ is an arbitrary local extension of $A(0)$ normal to $N$. In order to conclude $(\overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}X)^\top = (DA/ds(0))^\top$, I need to choose such an $X$ with the property that $X(\alpha(s)) = A(s)$ for $s$ close to $0$. Then, since my vector field $A(s)$ along $\alpha(s)$ is extendible (restricted to a small interval around $0$), the properties of the covariant derivative along curves gives me $DA/ds(0) = \overline{\nabla}_{J(0)}X$, which is what I want.

Comment: Am I looking at this correctly or am I overcomplicating it?